# describe extended table in Hive

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, lzo

I am storing the Table as a SequenceFile format and I am setting the below commands to enable Sequence with BLOCK Compression-

```
set mapred.output.compress=true;
set mapred.output.compression.type=BLOCK;
set mapred.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.LzoCodec;
```

But when I tried viewing the tables like this-

```
describe extended lip_table
```

I got below information in which there is a field called `compressed` which is set as `false`, So that means my data doesn't got compressed by setting the above three commands?

```
Detailed Table Information      Table(tableName:lip_table, dbName:default, owner:uname, 
createTime:1343931235, lastAccessTime:0, retention:0, sd:StorageDescriptor(cols:
[FieldSchema(name:buyer_id, type:bigint, comment:null), FieldSchema(name:total_chkout, 
type:bigint, comment:null), FieldSchema(name:total_errpds, type:bigint, comment:null)], 
location:hdfs://ares-nn/apps/hdmi/uname/lip-data, 
inputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileInputFormat, 
outputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveSequenceFileOutputFormat, 
**compressed:false**, numBuckets:-1, serdeInfo:SerDeInfo(name:null, 
serializationLib:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe, parameters:
{serialization.format=   , field.delim=
```

Comment: try `describe formatted` for a pretty-print of `describe extended`

Comment: I am running Hive 0.6 and it doesn't supports `describe formatted`.  :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this article](http://www.mrbalky.com/2011/02/24/hive-tables-partitions-and-lzo-compression/) that I think gives the solution to your problem.
You should rather try to specify the usage of your compression codec at the level of your table definition, either when creating the table or by using the ALTER statement.

At creation time:

```
 CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE lip_table (
                                    column1 string
                                  , column2 string 
                                 )
PARTITIONED BY (date string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY "\t"
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT "com.hadoop.mapred.DeprecatedLzoTextInputFormat"
          OUTPUTFORMAT "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat"
LOCATION '/path/to/hive/tables/lip';
```

Using ALTER (only affects partitions created subsequently):

```
ALTER TABLE lip_table
SET FILEFORMAT
    INPUTFORMAT "com.hadoop.mapred.DeprecatedLzoTextInputFormat"
    OUTPUTFORMAT "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat";
```

http://www.mrbalky.com/2011/02/24/hive-tables-partitions-and-lzo-compression/

Comment: I use above sql ,but it gives me the following error  FAILED: ParseException line 4:73 mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting SERDE near ''org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'' in file format specification

Answer (score 1):

To avoid `serde` exception use `serde` class too.

```
ALTER TABLE <<table name>>
SET FILEFORMAT
INPUTFORMAT "<<Input format class>>"
OUTPUTFORMAT
"<<Output format class>>" SERDE "<<Serde class>>";
```